# Toggle atualizar banco de dados Mysql automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Como posso fazer para que através do toggle eu atualizar minha base de dados? Tenho o toggle abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<div class="onoff">
  <strong>Desabilitar notificações por e-mail:</strong>
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="onoff">
  <label for="onoff"></label>
  <input type="hidden" name="Avisar" id="campo1" value="0">
</div>

......

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
var onoff = document.getElementById('onoff');
onoff.addEventListener('change', function() {
    estado = this.checked ? 'S' : 'N';
    var campo = document.getElementById("campo1").value = estado;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'notificacoes.php',
        type: 'post',
       data: {
           estado: this.checked,
           campo: campo
       }       
   }).done(function(msg) {
   });
});
}//]]>
///////////////////
</script>
```

E o PHP:

```
....
$idUsuarios = $_SESSION["IdUsuarios"];
$status = $_POST["estado"];
....
mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE tabela SET Notificacoes = '".$status."' WHERE IdUsuario = '".$idUsuarios."';
```

Só que não está atualizando. O problema está no **Jquery**, pois o **PHP** está funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Já tentou passar o data como string? Ex.: data: "estado="+this.checked+"&campo="+campo

Comment: Você utilizou um `var_dump` no php ou um alert no `javascript` pra saber se a requisição está sendo chamado quando o toggle é modificado?

Comment: tenta colocar um alert no addEventListener para ver se ele está sendo chamado.

Comment: Olá pessoal. Sobre passar como string, fiz e não passou os valores. Dei um alert conforme pediram e o valor (S ou N) está chegando corretamente. Isolamos o PHP e fizemos um teste diretamente nele e está funcionando, por isso descartamos que o problema seja no PHP.

Comment: O valor desejado chega no php?

Comment: Sim... o que estou achando estranho é que mesmo os valores sendo "S" e "N", quando dou um echo na variável `$status` e um console.log(data), ele me retorna "TRUE" ou "FALSE" e não "S" ou "N". Quando uso um ternário no PHP, ele passa a retornar somente TRUE.

Comment: Quando dou console.log(estado), ele aparece normalmente S ou N.

Comment: É como se realmente o valor não estivesse passando para o PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não entendi muito bem a diferença de **estado** e **campo**, mas creio que campo vai passar qual é o campo que você deseja ativar ou desativar as notificações e o estado é o sim e não.

Se este for o caso, sugiro alterar:

```
var campo = document.getElementById("campo1").value = estado;
```

para:

```
var campo = document.getElementById("campo1").value;
```

pois o campo1 estava mudando seu valor quando trocava o estado. (Caso isso deva ocorrer ignore esta parte)

Depois você definiu o estado como S ou N mas puxou novamente o **this.checked**

```
estado: this.checked,
```

Quando deveria ser:

```
estado: estado
```

Espero que isso te ajude!

Comment: Ajudou muito Henrique. Muito obrigado!